# Why do I get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED attempting to open a specific job using OpenPrinter?

Tags: c#, windows, print-spooler-api

According to [undocprint](http://www.undocprint.org/winspool/spool_files) given a job ID it should be possible to retrieve the spool file for the job using `OpenPrinter` and `ReadPrinter` by opening the printer using a string with format "PrinterName,Job xxxx". The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) lists this method as well, though with an additional space after the comma "PrinterName, Job xxxx".

Whenever I try to call this method from my test application (using either string format) I get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (Windows 8 x64). Why is this and what do I need to do to get this working?

I'm running the test app as admin and have no trouble pausing jobs or printers or accessing other information.

I know the ID I'm using is valid because for an invalid ID it returns `ERROR_INVALID_PRINTER_NAME` instead.

The code I'm using:

```
public static void OpenPrinter(String printerName,
                               ref IntPtr printerHandle,
                               ref PRINTER_DEFAULTS defaults) {
    if (OpenPrinter(printerName, ref printerHandle, ref defaults) == 0) {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(),
                                 string.Format("Error getting access to printer: {0}", printerName));
    }
}

[DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
    ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int OpenPrinter(String pPrinterName, ref IntPtr phPrinter, ref PRINTER_DEFAULTS pDefault);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PRINTER_DEFAULTS {
    public IntPtr pDatatype;
    public IntPtr pDevMode;
    public uint DesiredAccess;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that `pDefaults` must be passed `NULL` and then everything works.

This requires changing the extern definition to take an IntPtr or similar.

I haven't seen any documentation about why this might be (in fact the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) state that this passing `NULL` should be the same as requesting USE access), but it definitely fixes the issue in our testing.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions. Are you running with administrator rights?

Comment: Yes, the application is being run as administrator and I have no problem opening the printer itself and pausing the job or the printer. It's only when I try to open a specific job that I get this error.

Comment: Are you passing PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER or PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS for DesiredAccess?