# FindNextPrinterChangeNotification vs win32_printjob JobId

Tags: c#, wmi-query, print-spooler-api

I'm trying to get print jobs details generated from windows (AD based) print server which is serving more than 100s of client machines.

As I need to store some other details along with job details, used FindNextPrinterChangeNotification to get jobId at client(s) & passed that to WMI at server to get more job details.

Please refer both http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51085/Monitor-jobs-in-a-printer-queue-NET and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ocleon/2008/03/26/get-print-jobs-using-wmi-and-managmentobjects/

But the thing is I'm getting different ids for same job at both server & client (for example: 29956 & 29).

Can anyone explain how to handle jobids between this two Apis and arrive a solution for this issue.

Edit 1: 
From domain client machines by connecting the print server (\ipaddress) and executing the FindNextPrinterChangeNotification method, got jobinfo details (jobid 29956). But at the server by executing the select query to wmi win32-printjob class, yields no results at all and what I got previously was clients local print jobid (29).

Can anyone shed some light on how to get job details at print server by executing wmi queries locally.

Comment: "for example: **29**956 & **29**" -- Are those numbers real examples? If so, that's kind of suspicious. Are the first two digits always the same?

Comment: Yes. Those are real numbers. 1st two digit of 29XXX are always same  and small numbers are varying a lot. Today that small one already reached 7x. Currently am using WMI event listener at client machines, now I could get all the data about print job except page counts.

Comment: I would examine my own code very carefully for bugs. That pattern looks suspiciously like a number being corrupted somehow.

Comment: Hi @CareyGregory, Thanks for your help. I have double checked my code. When it is running at domain client machine 2 jobids created onle for local machine (29XXX) and the same code running at print server got only one jobid (75). Also do you have any idea about GetJob win32 function, currently am using it for pages count but could not get any result. My code flow is OpenPrinter --> GetJob --> ClosePrinter.

Comment: I don't know of any way to get accurate page counts from anywhere except the spool file. That has been a problem with GetJob for a ridiculous number of years now. Microsoft obviously doesn't care to bother fixing it.

Comment: Once again, Thanks for clarification about GetJob. Could you please let me know how to get page counts from spool file. I already paused & resumed the printjob using WMI (to get page counts through GetJob).

Comment: Can I use ReadPrinter to get pagecounts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866711/how-do-i-find-the-spool-file-for-the-job-with-a-given-id-even-when-spool-file-po

Comment: Yes you can. You'll need to parse the file yourself and you'll need to know the format to do that. http://www.undocprint.org/formats/winspool/spl

Comment: Thanks a ton @CareyGregory. I will check the ReadPrint function & let you know the results. Also, is it a good idea to use SNMP total print count differences captured between (WMI) paused & resumed printjob  like http://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/HowDoesHardwareCheckingAffectPrintingSpeed

Comment: Hi @CareyGregory.  Does ReadPrinter function itself won't give the data, do I really need do parsing? Do you know how to parse the .spl file with C#?

Comment: You should be able to do it in C#, C or C++ since all of them can call the Win32 APIs. How to parse the spool file is a project of its own. It's laid out very much like an EMF file, if you're familiar with those. Anyway, that's not a question someone can answer here. The answer would be hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: Hi @CareyGregory, I tried to read the file using www.codeproject.com/Articles/10586/EMF-Printer-Spool-File-Viewer. But I could not catch the file when it was created because the printjob has been already paused & resumed through WMI win32_PRINTJOB's _InstanceDeletionEvent. Always getting exception like 'Could not find file 'C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\00085.SPL' Do you have any idea like when we can pause in order to read the spool file? Please suggest.